# Where the smpt configuration is located in solaris

Tags: linux, unix, smtp, solaris, smtpclient

I am would like to know where can I find (in case it exists) the smtp configuration parameters under unix solaris.

Comment: You probably got downvoted because SMTP is a standard, not an implementation. sendmail and postfix are examples of implementations of the standard. Solaris comes with sendmail by default but postfix (which many consider to be superior) is pretty easy to get up and running on Solaris as well. In order for anyone to give you a proper answer you would also need to specify if you use Solaris 11 or some ancient version of Solaris.

Comment: @nolan6000 also because questions not about programming are considered _off-topic_.

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris 10 and 11 using the stock Sendmail (packages SUNWsndmr/SUNWsndmu), the following will show your config file location:

```
$ svccfg -s svc:/network/smtp:sendmail listprop config-file/entities 
config-file/entities fmri        file://localhost/etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

A useful guide of what to actually do with this configuration can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4555/mailadmin-43/index.html).